# Not able to establish connection to database using shell scripts when reading from properties file

Tags: database, shell

I am trying to read from properties file and trying to connect to oracle in shell script

Properties file:

```
#  DB Credentials
DbUser=CHRDPK68
DbPwd=CHRDPK68
DbSid=CHRDDPT9
#No Of Days to keep partition for
NO_OF_DAYS=1
```

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#reading from properties file
. ./config/PurgeTool.properties

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then  
 echo "Please enter no days"
 exit 1
fi

echo "Days are: $1"  

user=$DbUser
pwd=$DbPwd
sid=$DbSid

echo $user
echo $pwd
echo $sid   

sqlplus -s user/pwd@sid<<EOF
SET HEAD OFF
SET AUTOPRINT OFF
SET TERMOUT ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

@ ./sql/delete_partition.sql $1

EOF
```

It is giving below issue but variables from properties file are echoed correctly

CHRDPK68
CHRDPK68
CHRDPT9

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]]
where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
Have executed the script
```

but when am replacing sql line with :

```
sqlplus -s CHRDPK68/CHRDPK68@CHRDPT9<<EOF
```

it is successfully executing .sql script
I did try all permu and combo thinking that it might be to do with word being string but no luck included inside single , double quote but still error remains same

Comment: You need to make sure the props file is sourced at all. Add smth like ```echo "Props included!"``` at the end of your props file and run your script. If all goes well you should see echo output.

Comment: yes when i echo $DbUser it is printing successfully CHRDPK68, that means property file is being read but don't know why it is not able to connect when i am using props values

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
sqlplus -s user/pwd@sid<<EOF
...
```

And the correct way would be this:

```
sqlplus -s ${user}/${pwd}@${sid}<<EOF
```

Comment: i tried it, still no luck ,after debugging i am finding that \r is getting appended with variables. So need to create variables properly in properties file.

Comment: You might have the line endings in Win format for some reason. Try running ```dos2unix``` on your props and script files.